# Proper Razor syntax to use cms field as url for rss feed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, syntax, rss

I'm brand new to writing in Razor and am having some trouble figuring out proper syntax. I have written code that will embed and display rss feed content in a .html page:

```
@using System.Xml.XPath;
@using System.Xml;

@{
    //Fetch RSS XML
    XmlTextReader udBrudRSS = new XmlTextReader("http://www.website.com/feed.rss");

    //Create new XML document
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    //Load in our remote XML into our XML document
    doc.Load(udBrudRSS);

    //Select our nodes we want with some xPath
    XmlNodeList rssItems = doc.SelectNodes("//item");

}
<ul>
    @{
        //For each item node we can then ouput what we want
        foreach (XmlNode node in rssItems)
        {
            <li>
                <div class="date">@node["pubDate"].InnerText</div>
                <div class="message">@node["title"].InnerText</div>
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

This takes the content from feed.rss and embeds each post as a list item. Perfect. Now, to make this a bit more scalable and dynamic, I'd like to control the feed url through a field inside a cms. So I set the field's data as a variable like this:

```
var RssFeed = Model.Element("RssFeed");
```

And was successfull in printing this data on the page like this

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("Editable/_RawData", RssFeed);}
```

So I know that the data is successfully passing from the database to the page. But what I can't figure out is how to combine these two so users can control the feed without touching the template. Basically something like this:

```
XmlTextReader udBrudRSS = new XmlTextReader("@RssFeed");
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Anything within @{} is interpreted as C# code.  So as long as your XmlTextReader line is with an @{} section you would use the variable name directly without quotes and without the @.  The @ is used to signal when code starts.  So it would look like this as long as it's withing a @{} code block and you have a variable name RssFeed:

```
XmlTextReader udBrudRSS = new XmlTextReader(RssFeed);
```

You could rewrite your foreach loop like this:

```
@foreach (XmlNode node in rssItems)
{
    <li>
        <div class="date">@node["pubDate"].InnerText</div>
        <div class="message">@node["title"].InnerText</div>
    </li>
}
```

which is the preferred way to do it.  This way you're mixing code and HTML and using @ to reference C# variables.

Here's a good quick reference to Razor syntax:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

Comment: THanks for the advice @RyanB. I failed to mention that I did in fact try to just include the variable name at first(as that seemed the most obvious) but recieved a compiler error '
Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.XmlTextReader.XmlTextReader(System.Xml.XmlNameTable)' has some invalid arguments' which is what led me to believe I was not writing my razor correctly. I'll look over the syntax ref that will be a lot of help while I learn this!

Comment: That error probably means your variable is not the correct type.

Comment: YES. Thank you. I can't believe I made such a simple mistake and didn't catch it. In case anyone sees this with a similar problem here is the correct variable I needed 'string RssFeedDrillDown = Model.GetElementValue("RssFeed");'